# Filtering Data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

What happens when I filter data in Power BI data?

I am connecting to Analysis Services and loading data from a cube and then filtering it on the Year column = "2022".

What happens to previous years' data? While the historical data is not used for the report will it cause performance issues to load all the data from the source or does filtering restricts data load to only the filter criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends where you have filtered.

- If you filter the other years out in power query, you'll only get 2022 in Power BI. This may affect import time a little bit.
- Power BI itself is working with subsets. If you're using a page filter for the year 2022, it creats a subset, containing only the 2022 rows. So the other years won't affect the performance. But the file will get bigger and maybe opening lasts a bit longer compared with filtering them out in power query. Advantage: On other pages you still have the full dataset including the years before 2022.

Comment: I am filtering during the transformation process in the power query.  Does this mean only 2022 data is present in the report dataset as well? When you say "only get 2022" does it refer to loading 2022 data into memory while the dataset itself will contain all years data? Because after loading I can still change the filter and I can see other years data.

Comment: If you filter in power query, the other years won't be in memory. Power query won't import them.

Comment: What I am not clear is does filtering impacts the volume of data loaded into the memory or the size of the dataset file or both?

Comment: If you import full data, it will impact memory and file size. Nevertheless with page filter Power BI is creating subsets of the data, so can work on this page with a smaller (faster) dataset. Or with other words, if you are using filters, Power BI does calculations only on the in this context filtered rows.